# Как составить условие для проверки файлов на совпадение?

Tags: java, if

Добрый день, на сервер приходят файл который в первую очередь сравниваются по имени на совпадение и если имена равны то следующая проверка на размер и если размеры равны то идет команда клиенту, что такой файл есть и закачивать его не надо. Но тут вылезла проблема один файл совпал условие выполнилось но проверка продолжается и с остальными файлами которые есть он не совпадает. И это тоже надо как отразить в условии. Помогите разобраться.

```
File folder = new File("D://Photo_and_Video"); // доступ к папке с файлами
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); // получаем список файлов

if (listOfFiles.length > 0) { // проверяем не пустая ли папка
    for (File f: listOfFiles) {

        if (fileName.equals(f.getName())) { // проверяем наличее файла по имени

            if (fileSize == f.length()) { // проверяем файлы по размеру
                System.out.println("Файлы совпадают");

            }
        }
    }
} else {
    //папка пустая файлы закачать
}
```

Comment: Возможно после System.out.println("Файлы совпадают");   стоит вызвать break; чтобы прервать цикл, если я вас правильно понял

Comment: Что может быть проще `break`?

Comment: @Werder тоже думал break но с ним всё также

Comment: а у меня вопрос, зачем искать файл по имени?? нельзя просто file.exists() сделать?

Comment: @VargSieg, то есть вы хотите сказать что после команды break цикл все еще продолжается? Уточните дебаггером или логированием этот момент

Comment: @pavel поставьте в ответ свой вопрос )

Comment: @VargSieg рекомендую считать md5 сумму, если вам и содержимое файла тоже интересует

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я предлагаю вообще не делать этот поиск а сделать примерно так:

```
File folder = new File("D://Photo_and_Video"); //было
File newFile = new File(folder,f.getName());
if (newFile.exists()){
         //что там уже дальше проверять надо.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте оператор `break`

```
if(fileName.equals(f.getName()) && fileSize == f.length()){
   System.out.println("Файлы совпадают");   
   break;
}
```

Если же вы сравнивайте текстовые файлы можете использовать *org.apache.commons API* а именно `FileUtils.contentEquals(file1,file2)`

Answer (score 2):

Если Ваше ПО собирается работать с большим количеством файлов, то, вероятно (точно сказать не могу без знания контекста), используемый метод сверки неверен в корне.

Во-первых, работа с файловой системой - далеко не самая быстрая операция, к тому же - ресурсоёмкая. Во-вторых, логика Вашего ПО даже не предполагает случаев наличия идентичных файлов с разным именем.

На мой взгляд, более надёжным и рациональным способом был бы следующий подход:

1. Создать таблицу в базе данных, которая будет хранить сведения о всех имеющихся файлах, такие, как: имя файла, его местонахождение в файловой системе, тип, размер, **[хеш-сумму](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)** (*контрольная сумма, дайджест*), и др. По полю `хеш-суммы` следует создать индекс.
2. При загрузке нового файла следует сформировать его `хеш-сумму`. Для этого можно использовать `java.security.DigestInputStream.digest()` и `java.security.MessageDigest` (как применять - вопрос отдельный, ищите здесь, на SO, и в Google). Вот простейший пример копирования файла с подсчётом хеш-суммы "на лету":

   ```
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:\\Новый текстовый документ.txt");
   MessageDigest md;
   md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
   DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(fis, md);
   Files.copy(dis, new File("c:\\test.txt").toPath());

   byte[] digest = md.digest();
   String md5 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest);
   System.out.println(md5);
   ```

   Можете сами убедиться в том, что при изменении имени файла хеш остаётся неизменным.
3. Сам файл сохраняется так же, как и сейчас у Вас реализовано, плюс запись о нём сохраняется в БД. После подсчёта хеша нового файла, но до его сохранения следует осуществить поиск в БД файла с таким хешем (при наличии индекса по полю с хешем - очень быстрая операция), и если найден - то отрабатывать логику Вашей Системы для такого случая.

Кроме более "правильного" подхода к решению задачи, Вы также получаете и ответ на непосредственно заданный вопрос. Ответ заключается в том, что никакого цикла проверки не надо вообще, при поиске в БД Вы одним запросом получите список **всех** совпадающих файлов, либо пустой список в случае если совпадений нет.